# Make downloaded script work in index.php

Tags: php, include

I am kind of a beginner in PHP. Don't know if this question is asked before (couldn't find it). 
I created a website at index.php. Let's say, www.mysite.com/index.php.
Because i'm not a good programmer at all, i downloaded a membersystem script. This memberscript is located at, lets say, mysite.com/members/login.php (filename isn't that important yet i guess.).

What i want to do, is if somebody clicks on the "Login" button (located at index.php), members/login.php to be opend in index.php.

My problem is, if i use `switch($_GET['page']` in index.php the scripts doesn't work properly or links in login.php don't work (even if i made a case for that link). Sometimes it even opens the wrong links.

What's the best way to make an downloaded script (./members) work in my excisting site. (index.php is in root folder).

Thanks!

Update:

!-- Form Code Start -->
div id='fg_membersite'>
form id='login' action='GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
fieldset >
legend>Login

Removed the < in the beginning of the scripts to make sure it's published in here.

```
//-------Public Helper functions -------------
function GetSelfScript()
{
    return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}    

function SafeDisplay($value_name)
{
    if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
    {
        return'';
    }
    return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
}

function RedirectToURL($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

function GetSpamTrapInputName()
{
    return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->rand_key);
}

function GetErrorMessage()
{
    if(empty($this->error_message))
    {
        return '';
    }
    $errormsg = nl2br(htmlentities($this->error_message));
    return $errormsg;
}
```

Comment: You can redirect the user to `./members`..

Comment: Do i have to do that for every single file within members? And how do i link "Click here to login"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you can make a user go to `./members` folder and login..

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/members"; ?>" />click here to login</a>
```

Or if your login firm doesn't have a captcha or anything which avoids posting login details from another page, then you can simply make a form on index.php and keep it's action as the same file for login form.

Comment: Thanks, but the members dir contains 18 files and 3 subdirectories. Is this a way to include the entire script?

Comment: @TristanN. It's not including any file, it will make the user go to the `members` directory, in the login file, there will be a line `header(Location: index.php)` you can change index.php to whichever page you want the user to go after successful login, and you check for sessions if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: indead. the loginscript is connected to a registerscript, mail validationscript and more scripts like memberprofiles etc etc. i would like all those scripts to work within my index page.

Comment: Thank you blo. this means i should redirect to login.php or register.php to make the script work. this is the best option in your opinion?

Comment: @TristanN. Yes, or if you can show the code of your form, I can show you an easy way on how to do it from other pages..

Comment: <div id='fg_membersite'>
<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Login</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='username' >UserName*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" />

Comment: @TristanN. I'll need to know what the function `GetSelfScript();` looks like, can you edit your question with that part of the code?

Comment: done. There is another part in that script that gives me some trouble. The header("Location: ") part. What's the best to do there? Just the index.php?

Comment: @TristanN. the index.php in `header("Location index.php");` can't be changed as it's the file name to where the user goes after login, you can change it if you want him to go somewhere else..

Comment: And for logging in the users from different page, copy paste the html form as it is and then change action to `login.php` in the form tag..

Answer (score 1):

You can set the login link to go to `index.php?login=true`

Then your if statement will look like this:

```
if ($_GET['login'] == true)
```

Then, within the if statement, you can do:

```
include('./members/login.php');
```

To display the login.php script within index.php.

Or, if you want to fully redirect the user to login.php, just have the link go directly to `./members/login.php`.

Comment: Thanks, but the members dir contains 18 files and 3 subdirectories. Is this a way to include the entire script?

Comment: @TristanN. I'm not sure exactly what you mean. This will include the single script `login.php`. It's very possible that login.php includes some of the other scripts. Was that your question? If not, please be a little clearer.

Comment: @yortzec he meant, let's say `login.php` includes another file, like `include("db.php");` if it's so, your include function will possibly give an error..

Comment: indeed. but beside db.php there is also profile.php, logout.php, register.php etc etc. i would like the entire system to work in my index (index is in my root folder, the others scripts are in root/members/scriptname.php